# Can you identify this Nusakh of Tehillim?

Tags: tehilim-psalms, nuschaot, trop-cantillation

I am looking to master TUNISIAN (or Polish) nusakh for Tehillim, but am having trouble finding it. Can anyone identify the Tehillim Nusakh on this website?

http://www.sephardichazzanut.com/Tehillim.htm

Thank you so much. If you have any more resources for Tehillim Nusakh (Tunisian or Polish), please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

In their "about me" page, the founder says that he is Shami (Damascene) Syrian. As a result, I would infer that the niggunim and te'amim are also Syrian rather than Maghrebi.

http://www.sephardichazzanut.com/about.htm